# Getting the controller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

In my view I create links via:

```
URL::action('NotSureWhatController@getIndex', 'id') }}
```

My view is a template that is used by a variety of different controllers, what's the best way to change the name of the controller in the action?

The only thing I can think of is setting a var in the controller and passing it through.

Is there a better way? Or a way to get the controller name?

I can't use 'as' in the route to name the controller either (as this is used for something else) so this won't work:

```
Route::currentRouteName()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**

You should create the URL directly in the controller, then pass it as a variable to the view. The view will just print the url.

**Option 2**

You pass the name of the controller as a variable to the view (always from the controller), then you use the escape values of the [blade templating](http://laravel.com/docs/templates#blade-templating) to print it inside your function to generate URLs.

**Option 3**

Using the [REQUEST](http://laravel.com/docs/requests#request-information) class to get information about the page.